# Sort cell in tableview by title (date)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sorting, date

How to sort the cell in the tableview by title (title is date in dd/mm/yyyy format)?

My code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"total item in table %lu",(unsigned long)self.items.count);
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndex:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell atIndex:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

            // Get current Item
            Item *item = self.items[indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = item.name; // HERE IS DATE in dd/mm/yyyy format
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.itemDetails.note;

            /*
            NSArray *productsOrdered = nil;
            productsOrdered = [self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];
             */
        }
}
```

I get this:

[image: simulator image]

It's not sorted correctly.
I need the newest date up and older dates down in the list.

Comment: Sort `self.items`. You can use a `NSDateFormatter` to have a date and sort. I don't know how you create the `Item`, but I'd add a `NSDate` property to be quickly used for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sort `self.items` however you'd like to before calling `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: If I use this: NSSortDescriptor* sortByDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
            [self.items sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByDate]];
It doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you call that? What are the contents of items before and after? Are you reloading the table afterwards?

Comment: I call that in - (void)configureCell:... But when I try [self.tableView reload]; I get error: "No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'reload'". And I wrote that in the end of code.

Comment: That's a method that is getting called while creating your cells.  Stick the sort in viewDidLoad, then call `[self.tableView reloadData];` sorry for the typo

Comment: If you sort + call reloadData where you said, you're going to be in an infinite loop of reloading, configuring the first cell, sorting, reloading, etc.  You want to sort once, before your table is displayed, and then have it load the sorted data.

Comment: OK, thank you, I put it in viewDidLoad, but the dates are not sorted by date... The problem is the same like in the beginning.

Comment: You do have self.items instantiated there, yeah? Or where do you set up self.items? Can you post your viewDidLoad code and any code where you're updating self.items?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vrgv2uiv17clgko/AACXHXEhyLL6CQtKZ8AeARwna?dl=0 There are 2 files. In BeerViewController.m I save the Items (=Beers). The MasterView.m is where I use tableview and where is my problem.

Comment: One note is to always call `[super viewDidLoad];` at the beginning of your override, not the end.  It might undo some of the stuff you do yourself. There are only a couple exceptions for the VC default methods where you don't want to call the super first.